# 'std::vector' : 'U64' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors

I have a header SomeDefines.h that includes

```
#define U64 unsigned long long
#define U16 unsigned short
```

In Myclass.h, I `#include SomeDefines.h` at the top.

In the Myclass declaration, I have a function

```
bool someFunc(const std::vector<U64>& theVector);
```

and a member variable
    tbb::atomic someNumber;

When I compile in Visual Studio 2012, I get the errors

```
error: 'U64': undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'std::vector': 'U64' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
```

The errors go away if I replace the `U64` with `unsigned long long`

```
bool someFunc(const std::vector<unsigned long long>& theVector);
```

I thought the compiler would see the `#define U64 unsigned long long` and replace `U64` with `unsigned long long`.

Why am I getting these errors for the `U64` and not the `U16`?

Comment: BTW, you may use `typedef` (or `using`) instead of macro.

Comment: It appears you have a clash of include guards. Fix that then refactor to use a typedef.

Comment: You're getting the errors because `U64` is not defined at that point. Anyway define a type instead of a macro. Or better, use the `<stdint.h>` types.

Comment: Note: there is a <cstdint> giving you a `uint64_t`

Comment: Are you using precompiled header file (`stdafx.h`) ? If you are, try put your includes *after* that

Comment: I've added some info to hopefully clarify the problem.  @Bathsheba if I had a clash of include guards, why might I see the difference between the `U64` and `U16`?

Comment: I imagine that seeing the output of the preprocessor would clear up everyone's confusion as to what is going on here. @user3731622: Could you provide that?

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is not a good idea for creating new types. Prefer `typedef` or `using`:

```
typedef unsigned long long U64;
// or:
using U64 = unsigned long long;
```